# Nagios and SELinux - what are proper settings for Nagios files?

Tags: centos, security, selinux

I was trying to deploy Nagios on a VM running CentOS 7, and as most, ran into "Could not stat() nagios.cmd" problem. I did set permissions for users apache and nagios to acccess the file, and now am fighting with SELinux to both allow apache and nagios to modify the command file. The apparent problem is, Nagios got installed to `/usr/local/nagios` instead of `/usr/lib/nagios` which seems to be the predefined location for Nagios, based on `/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts` content. Currently, Apache process already running as `httpd_t`, while Nagios processes are running under `initrc_t` (default started by init) context. Current folder settings are all files under `system_u:object_r:usr_t:s0` context, starting from `/usr/local/nagios` and below.

So, I wonder, what context (user, role, type) I should set and where, regarding Nagios files, so I can safely enable SELinux and not run into either Nagios not starting, or Apache not able to modify the command file?

Comment: Please post the output of `cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow`

Comment: @shodanshok That might not be necessary, given the file/program context. This will at most add a workaround, but not provide a cure.

Comment: `audit2allow` does **not** automatically change anything. It simply suggest some modification to the SELINUX policy. Its output can be useful to understand what specific privilege SELINUX is not granting.

Comment: @shodanshok `audit2allow` plain curses "error 2 no such file `'/etc/selinux/targeted/contexts/files/file_contexts.local'`. The dir contains: file_contexts      file_contexts.homedirs      file_contexts.subs       media
file_contexts.bin  file_contexts.homedirs.bin  file_contexts.subs_dist

Comment: Your selinux policy seems corrupted. I suggest you to reinstall/update it and relabel the entire filesystem.

Comment: @shodanshok This is possible, if only there is a working context for nagios-4 installed in default location. From what I'm reading, my distro has contexts for nagios-3 only. Also the missing file problem was solved with `touch`.